# Why do I get an error "permission type field required" on google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to change permissions on some files and google drive returns an

> **Error**
>
> ```
> permission type field required
> ```

However I am supplying a type. So please can someone tell me what I am missing.

Note hauth is an oauth2 authorised http object.

```
#%% find files and list [This works fine]
q="title='testpop'"
u="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files"
u=u+"?"+urlencode(dict(q=q))
resp, content = hauth.request(u, "GET")

files = json.loads(content.decode("utf-8"))
for f in files["items"]:
    print(f["title"], f["id"])

#%% make public [this returns error "permission type field required"]
for f in files["items"]:
    u="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}/permissions" \
                        .format(fileId=f["id"])
    body = json.dumps(dict(role="reader", type="anyone"))
    headers=dict(content_length=len(body))
    resp, content = hauth.request(u, "POST", headers=headers, body=body)
    break
```

Here is the content returned:

```
 b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "required",\n    "message": "Permission type field required",\n    "locationType": "other",\n    "location": "permission.type"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 400,\n  "message": "Permission type field required"\n }\n}\n'
```

Comment: I think body should be body = dict(role="reader", type="anyone").

Comment: Actually body has to be a string. However you prompted me to try a json header and it works with headers={"content-type": "application/json"}. Thanks.